# Doubts in solving the integral $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin2x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I tried to solve the integral $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin2x}}dx$ by using $1+\sin2x=(\sin x+\cos x)^2$ but got stuck. So I referred the solution in my book which is given below:

$$
I=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin2x}}dx
$$
$$
= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\frac \pi 2+2x)}}dx\tag1\\
= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sin^2(\frac \pi 4+x)}}dx\\
=\frac 1 {\sqrt2} \int \csc\left(\frac \pi 4+x\right)dx\\
= \color{red}{\frac 1 {\sqrt2} \log\left|\tan\left(\frac \pi 8+\frac x 2\right)\right|+C}(*)
$$

I wondered what if I replaced $\sin 2x$ by $\cos\left(\frac \pi 2 -2x\right)$ instead of $-\cos\left(\frac \pi 2 +2x\right)$ in step $(1)$. So I proceeded as follows:

$$
I=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin2x}}dx
$$
$$
= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos(\frac \pi 2-2x)}}dx\\
= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos^2(\frac \pi 4-x)}}dx\\
=\frac 1 {\sqrt2} \int \sec\left(\frac \pi 4-x\right)dx\\
= \color{red}{\frac 1 {\sqrt2} \log\left|\tan\left(\frac {3\pi} 8-\frac x 2\right)\right|+C}(**)
$$

But I got a different result. Could you please explain the reason for this anomaly? Is it wrong to do a different replacement in step $(1)$? I think it shouldn't make any difference.

Further, could you please explain how to think we must be doing the replacement instead of using $1+\sin2x=(\sin x+\cos x)^2$ to solve this integral? I got this idea only after looking the solution.

---

*Using $\int \csc x dx=\log\left|\tan\left(x/2\right)\right|+C$

**Using $\int \sec x dx=\log\left|\tan\left(\frac \pi 4 +\frac x 2\right)\right|+C$

Comment: Are you sure that this is different ?

Comment: You might want to check signs, since $\frac 1 {\sqrt2} \log\left|\tan\left(\frac {3\pi} 8-\frac x 2\right)\right| = - \frac 1 {\sqrt2} \log\left|\tan\left(\frac \pi 8+\frac x 2\right)\right|$

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I think yes. But it must be no. Is there anything wrong in my attempt?

Comment: @Henry, Could you please explain how you transformed the final solution obtained by me to the negative of the solution given in the book? Even then why is there a difference in the signs of the final expression?

Comment: My point is really that $\tan\left(\frac\pi 4+y\right)\, \tan\left(\frac\pi 4-y\right)=1$ so taking logarithms turns this into a sign change

Comment: See Henry's comments.

Comment: @Henry, Thank you. Now I understood your first comment. But why is there a difference in sign? Will this effect be balanced by the arbitrary constant in some way?

Comment: @M.GuruVishnu the sign problem is because you have two cases: $\sqrt{t^2}=|t|=\pm t$, so for the first case, you will have the antiderivative with a plus, and for the second with a minus.

Comment: This step, $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos^2(\frac \pi 4-x)}}dx=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos^2(x-\frac\pi 4)}}dx=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sin^2(x-\frac\pi 4+\frac\pi 2)}}dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I prefer your first idea for its cuteness. You're only a step away, for you have that $$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt 2\sin\left(x+\fracπ4\right).$$

Then you would only want to do something which is a constant multiple of the form $$\int\csc y\mathrm dy,$$ which is a standard integral.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. I could have avoided this much trouble. If possible, could you please explain the reason for the inconsistency between the two methods used?

Comment: @M.GuruVishnu The problem is with the second method. What you have is a constant multiple of $$\int\sec\left(x-\fracπ4\right)\mathrm d\left(x-\fracπ4\right)=\log\left|\tan\left(\frac x2+\fracπ8\right)\right|+C,$$ as before. If you wanted to do it your way then you should have had $$\color{red}{-}\int\sec\left(\fracπ4-x\right)\mathrm d\left(\fracπ4-x\right)$$ instead (note the sign change).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin 2 x}} d x \\
& =\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\sin x+\cos{x})^2}} d x \\
& =\operatorname{sgn}(\cos{x}+\sin x) \int \frac{d x}{\cos x+\sin x} \\
& = \operatorname{sgn}(\cos x+\sin x)\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \cos \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)} d x \\
& =\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(\cos x+\sin x)}{\sqrt 2}  \ln \left|\sec \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\tan \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right| \\
& =\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(\cos x+\sin x) }{\sqrt{2}} \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt 2+\sin x-\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}\right|+C \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Neither
$\frac 1 {\sqrt2} \ln\left|\tan\left(\frac \pi 8+\frac x 2\right)\right|$ nor $\frac 1 {\sqrt2} \ln\left|\tan\left(\frac {3\pi}8-\frac x 2\right)\right|$ is correct. The anti-derivative valid over all domain is instead
$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin2x}}dx
= \frac{ \cos (x-\frac\pi4)}{\sqrt{1+ \sin 2x}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sin(x-\frac\pi4)\right)+C
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{1+sin2x}=\sqrt{(sinx+cosx)^{2}}=\sqrt{2}\left| sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) \right|\\
z=x+\frac{\pi}{4}\Rightarrow dz=dx\\
\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+sin2x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{dz}{\left| sinz \right|}\\
1)sinz\gt 0\\
\displaystyle\int\frac{dz}{\left| sinz \right|}=\int\frac{sinzdz}{sin^{2}z}=\int\frac{sinzdz}{1-cos^{2}z}\\
(y=cosz)\to \displaystyle \int\frac{dz}{\left| sinz \right|}=-\int\frac{dy}{1-y^{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}\int(\frac{1}{1+y}+\frac{1}{1-y})dy=-ln\sqrt{1-y^{2}}+c\\
\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+sin2x}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}ln\left| sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) \right|+c\\
2)sinz\lt 0\\
\displaystyle\int\frac{dz}{\left| sinz \right|}=-\int\frac{dz}{sinz}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}ln\left| sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) \right|+c$